# Form values in URL

Tags: javascript, function, url, parameters

I have a function that puts my URL together. It looks like this:

```
$url = "/BT_Mathys_LNr_export_0.1/services/BT_Mathys_LNr_export?method=runJob";
$i = 1
$('#myForm :input').each(function() {
  $inputName = $(this).attr('name');
  if ($inputName != 'submit') {
    $url = $url + "&arg"+$i+"=--context_param%20"+$inputName+"="+$(this).val();
    $i++
  };
});
```

The function adds my values from the input fields together in my URL and it worked perfectly until now. Now I have to add a `<select>` in my form and have to pass that value also, exactly like I do with the values from the input fields.

How can I add in the code that my value from the `<select>` will also be included as a parameter in the URL exactly like the input fields?

Comment: why don't you use form with GET method

Comment: It looks like you're passing user input to a command line application, if so there could be serious issues with not sanitising the data on the server side.  I would recommend submitting the form normally and building the arguments on the server after sanitising the input.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jQuery to do that: `$("#your_form").serialize();`

Comment: If you look at his code, you'll see that serialize() won't produce the format he desires.

Comment: In case you want to add a `<select>` control, serialize might not work, to workaround I think you should add a hidden field to store the selected option of select, and `serialize()` will do the rest for you.

Comment: I was also thinking that i could make one hidden input field after the select and add the value from select to the input field. Then i don't have to change anything in my scripts becuase it's working fine like it is now. The problem is i don't know how to pass the value that's choosen in the select to my hidden input field? Can you pls help me solve that..

Comment: You could try this: `$("#hidden").val($("select option:selected").val());`

Comment: Thanks but im a real noobie and still don't know where i should put this $("#hidden").val($("select option:selected").val()); :D

Comment: It has to look like something like this: <tr><td> Employee </td> <td class="arg"><select><option value="j@hotmail.com" name="email">Jan</option><option value="d@hotmail.com" name="email">Dan</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="email" value="valuefrommyselect">

Comment: You have to add to onchange event of select control, `$(function(){$("select").change($("#hidden").val($("select option:selected").val()););});`

Comment: Okey how must the input look like? Ive tried now without a hidden field to see if i get some value in the input field when i change in the select but it's still empty.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add a `<select>` control, serialize might not work, to workaround I think you should add a hidden field to store the selected option of select, and `serialize()` will do the rest for you.